# Is it worth completely changing “acceptable” bath vent ducting to avoid reducing from 4” fan to 3” ducting?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, ducts, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I’m upgrading two adjacent small bathrooms with new exhaust fans. The existing ducts are 3” plastic/flexible. The builder has both 3” ducts terminating, side by side, out of a 5or6” roof vent. The new fan has a 4” attachment. Is it worth adding a second roof vent? In researching, I know that using a Y to join them would not be ideal, even with dampers. I already have the new fan and am not looking for in-line, etc. I also know that new fans could be slightly louder and less efficient if reduced, but they are such an improvement from what was there, I don’t know that it’s worth all the effort. Advise?

Comment: 'Worth the effort' is an opinion question, so here's an opinion rather than an answer: I did a couple of fan upgrades at my previous house re-using the existing 3 inch ducts, and I would do it again in a second. The new ones were so much better than the old ones. A 4 inch duct would have been even better.

Comment: I think you're proposing a false dichotomy here. I would reconfigure the existing roof vent for 4" tributaries before I would create another hole in the roof. I would exchange the fans for 3" exhausted fans before I would create another hole in the roof.

Comment: Worth it?  It depends how easy it is to access the duct.  Attic with plenty of headroom?  Easy peasy lemon squeezy.  1st floor with living space above?  I'm leaving the 3" duct in place.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be cutting an extra hole in my roof for 2-4" ducts. Many of the fans I've installed actually came with 4" to 3" reducers and I used them with no problems. Using a "wye" can further reduce flow and can, in some cases, divert moist air from one bath into the next. Use  the 3" ducts and pull them as straight as possible with just enough slack to service the fan.